# Windows XP 64-bit Conexant Pebble HD Audio Driver

Tags: windows-xp, audio, drivers, 64-bit, downgrade

I have installed Windows XP 64-bit on my HP Pavilion G60T-500 CTO notebook PC and along with installing a non-factory OS came the struggle of finding drivers.  My audio device is a Conexant Pebble HD Smart Audio something-rather.  I don't know and cannot seem to find the exact device name or model, but here are some codes from Device Manager.

Hardware Assistance ID:

```
HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_14F1&DEV_5067&SUBSYS_103C360B&REV_1003\4&286848AF&0&0001
```

Hardware IDs:

```
HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_14F1&DEV_5067&SUBSYS_103C360B&REV_1003
HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_14F1&DEV_5067&SUBSYS_103C360B
```

Compatible IDs:

```
HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_14F1&DEV_5067&REV_1003
HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_14F1&DEV_5067
HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_14F1
HDAUDIO\FUNC_01
```

The device is listed as "Audio Device on High Definition Audio Bus."  I've tried both Vista 64 drivers and XP 32-bit just in case but to no avail.  Either a failed start or BSOD.

Again I must reiterate that this is XP 64-bit.  I've had 32-bit working in the past, but ideally I want to make 64-bit work if possible.  Where can I find a working driver for my Conexant Pebble HD Smart Audio device?  At the very least, is there a universal driver that will support this device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab the driver for it [here](http://driverzone.com/%7B50bb3715-0d4d-421d-bc39-ef7a205d3862%7D?id=1609241).  Both 32 bit and 64 bit XP drivers are available.

Comment: I don't know how you found that!  The installer doesn't work but forcing the driver through "have disk" works perfectly.  I've got sound now, thanks so much.

Comment: I copied your question title into google.  In lieu of good documentation on systems, there's no such thing as "overusing" a search engine.  Anyway, glad to hear you got it working.